# How I can to cut line segment video with ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I want to cut video from long-video with ffmpeg, I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i /home/nantembo/VideoPerl/1.mp4 -f avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 0:14:47 -t 0:58:55 /home/nantembo/VideoPerl/2.mp4
```

but I receive video duration 58:55 min with start position 0:14:47 + 0:44:08, but I need to receive video, which:

- starting at 0:14:47
- ending at 0:58:55

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `ffmpeg` manual, the `-t` option is the **duration**, not the *end time*.

I think you're looking for the `-to` option:

```
 -to position (output)
           Stop writing the output at position.  position must be a time duration specification, see the Time
           duration section in the ffmpeg-utils(1) manual.

           -to and -t are mutually exclusive and -t has priority.
```

So in your case, the command will be:

```
ffmpeg -i /home/nantembo/VideoPerl/1.mp4 -f avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 0:14:47 -to 0:58:55 /home/nantembo/VideoPerl/2.mp4
```